Spring-Batch JdbcCursorItemReader Connection Timeout When Pool Size Is 1
When creating a partitioned job in spring-batch that uses a JdbcCursorItemReader and a Hikari connection pool with maximumPoolSize=1, the partitioned step always throws CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open JDBC Connection for transaction at the very beginning of the step execution. This also occurs when gridSize is set to any value greater than the maximumPoolSize.
This somewhat implies that parallelism is limited to the maximum number of connections your pool can provide. What am I doing wrong here?
In the example below, I have maximumPoolSize=1 and gridSize=2 and the job always fails with:
org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open JDBC Connection for transaction
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager.doBegin(DataSourceTransactionManager.java:313) ~[spring-jdbc-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.startTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:531) ~[spring-tx-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:405) ~[spring-tx-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.createTransactionIfNecessary(TransactionAspectSupport.java:617) ~[spring-tx-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:386) ~[spring-tx-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119) ~[spring-tx-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:223) ~[spring-aop-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy49.updateExecutionContext(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep.doExecute(TaskletStep.java:234) ~[spring-batch-core-5.1.1.jar:5.1.1]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep.execute(AbstractStep.java:229) ~[spring-batch-core-5.1.1.jar:5.1.1]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.partition.support.TaskExecutorPartitionHandler.lambda$createTask$0(TaskExecutorPartitionHandler.java:132) ~[spring-batch-core-5.1.1.jar:5.1.1]

Setting maximumPoolSize=3 and gridSize=2 allows the job to complete succesfully.
Here is my job configuration:
@Configuration
@SpringBootApplication
public class AppConfiguration {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext ctx = SpringApplication.run(AppConfiguration.class, args);
        SpringApplication.exit(ctx);
    }

    @Autowired
    PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager;
    @Autowired
    JobRepository jobRepo;
    @Autowired
    DataSource dataSource;

    @Bean
    public Job mockJob() {
        return new JobBuilder("jobName", jobRepo).start(partitionedStep()).build();
    }

    @Bean
    Step partitionedStep() {
        return new StepBuilder("partitionedStep", jobRepo).partitioner(workStep())
                .partitioner("workerStep", new SimplePartitioner())
                .gridSize(2)
                .taskExecutor(taskExecutor())
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Step workStep() {
        return new StepBuilder("step1", jobRepo)
                .<String, String>chunk(2, transactionManager)
                .reader(reader())
                .writer(writer())
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public TaskExecutor taskExecutor() {
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor t = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        t.setCorePoolSize(10);
        t.setMaxPoolSize(10);
        return t;
    }

    @Bean
    @StepScope
    JdbcCursorItemReader<String> reader() {
        JdbcCursorItemReader<String> reader = new JdbcCursorItemReader<>();
        reader.setDataSource(dataSource);
        reader.setSql("SELECT 1");
        reader.setRowMapper((rs, i) -> rs.getString(1));
        reader.setPreparedStatementSetter(ps -> {
        });
        return reader;
    }

    @Bean
    @StepScope
    ItemWriter<String> writer() {
        return new ItemWriter<String>() {
            @Override
            public void write(Chunk<? extends String> chunk) throws Exception {
                System.out.println(chunk.toString());
            }
        };
    }
}

Here is my DataSource:
@Configuration
public class AppDataSourceConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public DataSource datasource() {
        HikariDataSource hikariDataSource = (HikariDataSource) DataSourceBuilder
                .create(HikariDataSource.class.getClassLoader())
                .username("sa").password("")
                .url("jdbc:h2:mem:atest;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=false")
                .driverClassName("org.h2.Driver")
                .build();
        hikariDataSource.setMaximumPoolSize(1);
        hikariDataSource.setConnectionTimeout(5000);
        return hikariDataSource;

    }

}

My pom is very simple and uses spring-boot-starter-batch version 3.2.5

If you are using 1 datasource for both reading and storing the spring batch meta-data I suspect you will always need at least 2 connections. 1 for the job and 1 for spring batch to write its metadata. They need seperate transactions so it cannot use one connection for that.
